# getting the price using amazon api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I was looking into Amazon API documentation and I found this code but could not figure out what is AssociateTag, Timestamp and Signature and where to get them, I only have my public and privet key and my amazon associate ID, I am trying to get a price of a product using the ASIN code

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
  Service=AWSECommerceService
  &Operation=ItemLookup
  &ResponseGroup=Offers
  &IdType=ASIN
  &ItemId=B00KOKTZLQ
  &AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
  &AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyId]
  &Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
  &Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

this code can be found on this link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html)

Comment: This page will help you. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AnatomyOfaRESTRequest.html

Comment: I believe you should get back an xml file, which you can parse for the price tag.